# Cython cdef class with C++ vector of C++ stack objects

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

In Cython it's really easy to create a Python extensions class of C++ vector of `int`

```py
# vector_int.pyx

# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.stack cimport stack
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
cdef class VectorInt:
    cdef vector[int] v
    
    def __cinit__(self, count):
        self.v = [0] * count  # <-- Works! Allocate variable length of zeros

    def set(self, idx, x):
        self.v[idx] = x

    def get(self, idx):
        return self.v[idx]
    

def test_vector_int_stack():
    v = VectorInt(11)
    v.set(0, 42)
    assert v.get(0) == 42
```

But how do I create a Python extension class of **vector of stack objects of int**?

```py
# vector_stack_int.pyx

# distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.stack cimport stack
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef class VectorStackInt:

    cdef vector[stack[long]] v
    
    def __cinit__(self, count):
        for i in range(count):
            self.v.push_back((new stack[long]()))  # <--- Error here?!

    def set(self, idx, x):
        self.v[idx].push(x)

    def get(self, idx):
        return self.v[idx].top()
```

This fails because `new` returns a pointer to the new stack,

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    cdef vector[stack[long]] v
    
    def __cinit__(self, count):
        for i in range(count):
            self.v.push_back((new stack[long]()))  # <--- Error here?!
                                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pvtracec/libs/simple.pyx:58:45: Cannot assign type 'stack[long] *' to 'stack[long]'
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `new`? i.e. exactly what you'd do in C++

Comment: Yes! I’ve just realised, was about to answer my own answer. Why not upgrade your comment to a answer for some free points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... just remove `new`.

Like, `malloc`, C++'s `new` allocates memory and returns a pointer to it. Here want actually want to reference the object directly.

```py
cdef class VectorStackInt:

    cdef vector[stack[long]] v
    
    def __cinit__(self, count):
        for i in range(count):
            self.v.push_back(stack[long]())  # <--- Remove `new`!

    def push(self, idx, x):
        self.v[idx].push(x)
    
    def pop(self, idx):
        self.v[idx].pop()

    def top(self, idx):
        return self.v[idx].top()
    

def test_vector_stack_int():
    v = VectorStackInt(11)
    v.push(0, 42)
    v.push(0, 43)
    v.top(0) == 43
    v.pop(0)
    v.top(0) == 42
```